# jQuery, Match and RegEx

Tags: jquery, regex, testing

So I have the following code in jQuery, and I am trying to essentially match dates in the format MM/YYYY where MM is a value between 1 and 12 and YYYY is a date in 1900s or 2000s. I haven't really used the jQuery test function before. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code or the Regex?

```
        var fieldValue = $(this).val();
        if(!fieldValue.test(([1-9]|1[0-2])/^(19|20)\d\d)){
            Errors = Errors + 1;
            $(this).addClass("form_error");             
        }
```

Comment: `text` doesn't belong to jQuery but to [RegExp prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

Comment: I don't know jQuery, but I doubt that's how you define a regex pattern. Anyway, that stray start-of-string anchor `^` is preventing your pattern from matching anything.

Comment: And the regex should be surrounded by `/` delimiters.

Comment: @Tushar, yeah, did not really pay attention, dwelled on the pattern only :) So,  `if(!/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((?:19|20)\d\d)/.test(fieldValue)) {`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several issues in the code:

- You need to use `RegExp#test(String)`, not `String#test(RegExp)`
- The pattern should appear in-between regex delimiters `/.../`
- The `/` must be escaped inside a regex literal
- If you validate an entire string, add `^` at the start and `$` anchors at the end of the pattern

Use

```
if(!/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((?:19|20)\d\d)$/.test(fieldValue)) {
```

Else, you may use `String#match` and check if a match was a asuccess or not

```
if(fieldValue.match(/^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((?:19|20)\d\d)$/)) {
```

The `0?` will allow an optional leading `0`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])` - Group 1: month, from `01` to `12`
- `\/`  - a `/`
- `((?:19|20)\d\d)` - Group 2: either `19` or `20` and then 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: `\d\d` ==> `\d{2}` can also be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

---

```
Date.prototype.fromString = function(string, ddmmyyyy) {
var m = string.match(/(\d+)(-|\/)(\d+)(?:-|\/)(?:(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?)?/);
if(m[2] == "/"){
    if(ddmmyyyy === false)
        return new Date(+m[4], +m[1] - 1, +m[3], m[5] ? +m[5] : 0, m[6] ? +m[6] : 0, m[7] ? +m[7] : 0, m[8] ? +m[8] * 100 : 0);
    return new Date(+m[4], +m[3] - 1, +m[1], m[5] ? +m[5] : 0, m[6] ? +m[6] : 0, m[7] ? +m[7] : 0, m[8] ? +m[8] * 100 : 0);
}
return new Date(+m[1], +m[3] - 1, +m[4], m[5] ? +m[5] : 0, m[6] ? +m[6] : 0, m[7] ? +m[7] : 0, m[8] ? +m[8] * 100 : 0);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/((19|20)\d\d)$ i have not tested it, but thats what the regex should look like